# Can not create a table in Azure storage emulator

Tags: azure

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure; // Namespace for CloudConfigurationManager
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; // Namespace for CloudStorageAccount
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table; // Namespace for Table storage types


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

                // Create the table client.
                CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

                // Retrieve a reference to the table.
                CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Demo");

                // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
                table.CreateIfNotExists();
                Console.WriteLine("Succ");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are trying to run this code in Visual Studio 2015. We getting the error while creating table in azure storage emulator.

[image: Getting this error while executing above code..]

Comment: Do you have Storage Emulator running?

Comment: Please ensure that storage emulator is running. Based on the error it seems the emulator is not running on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the Azure Storage Emulator is not running. Please make sure that you have started it as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator).

Basically you need to search for "Windows Azure Storage Emulator" in your programs and start it. A console window should open where you can control the emulator.

Let me know if that helps.